# Java replace matches with variables

Tags: java

```
/* Look for phone numbers starting with a 0 after a space
character and replace the 0 with "+44 (0)" */

    import java.util.regex.*;

    public class Reg6 {

        public static void main (String [] args) {

            String variable1 = "test";
            Pattern phone = Pattern.compile("\\s0");
            Matcher action = phone.matcher(args[0]);
            String worldwide = action.replaceAll(" +44 (0) ");
            System.out.println(worldwide);

        }
    }
```

How can I place a `variable1` into the replaceAll method? if there will be a string {$variable_1} i wish to replace it by my variable_1 is that possible?

its like in php template

"{$test}" - I want to use name that matches in the string and find that variable that matches to this  string and put it there replacing it all by this variable value

its just like in the templates

Comment: Your question is not very clear

Comment: String worldwide = action.replaceAll(variable1);

Comment: It's worth remembering though that replaceAll() expects regex as input

Comment: @MGorgon I mean imagine there a part of a string {$variable_1} - its just a string, but its a match to the variable that is in my program, so I want to find a variable in my program by this string(I mean the 'variable_1' part) and then put it his value into the string replacing it entirely with "{$variable_1}" - becomes "test"

Comment: i think it is better to check if number starts with 0. then if it starts with 0 get the substring starts from 1 to the end and add that to ur variable

Comment: What you want can be done with regex, but it requires more than a single method call. Take a look at [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from Apache Commons for a pre-built solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use Pattern or matches
Just try following

```
    String number ="028346";
    if(number.startsWith("0"))
        System.out.println("+44 (0)" + number.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this :

```
Pattern varMatch = Pattern.compile("\\{\\$variable_1\\}");
Matcher action = varMatch.matcher(worldwide);
worldwide = action.replaceAll(variable1);
System.out.println(worldwide);
```